# Conditional Split SSIS fails at runtime

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am using SQl Server 2012 and use the SSIS task Condition Split. In visual studio the Condition split works well, but when i deploy the package to SSIS and run it via SISSDB it fails during validation with the following message:

Component "CS Contains Seperator in DU, clsid {7F88F654-4E20-4D14-84F4-AF9C925D3087}" could not be created and returned error code 0x800703FA "Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion.". Make sure that the component is registered correctly.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio did you use?

Comment: Going with the obvious ones: have you ever deployed a package with a conditional split to this server that works? Is there something special in the expression on this CS? Has anything unusual happened to this server recently (patches, failover if clustered, etc)?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2012 with SSDT & SSDTBI

Comment: Try creating your package in Visual Studio 2010, which is the edition that is designed to work with SQL Server 2012.